# 'Display: contents' does not work with tree-structure pseudo-classes (:first-child,: last-child, etc.)?

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors, pseudo-class

My question: is this intentional? I can't find any literature or conversation about it.

The selector spec says it's for inclusive siblings - https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-index - but doesn't `display: contents` in effect simulate the contents as *belonging* to the grandparent element?

Per docs, the element is entirely removed from the accessibility-tree, and a grandparent flex will treat the removed element's children as its own (thus as siblings to its own). However, tree-structure pseudo-classes, such as `:last-child`, do not recognize the children's adoption, and instead operate as if they were still children of the removed element.

I suppose this is because the element is not removed from the actual DOM tree, and the pseudo selectors only operate upon the concrete DOM?

My use case is along the lines of:

```
<Accordion>
  <form style={{ display: contents }}>
    <Accordion.Section />
    <Accordion.Section />
  <form>
  <Accordion.Section />
</Accordion>
```

... In which I was expecting the `form` would display its children into the `Accordion` and I could select the last child.

Comment: From the official specification : *any semantics based on the document tree, such as selector-matching, event handling, and property inheritance, are not affected.* <-- Note the "selector-matching"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Question:

> but doesn't `display: contents` in effect simulate the contents as belonging to the grandparent element?

No, here's a quoted explanation from [here](https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2018/01/11/display-contents-is-coming/)

> `display: contents` makes that the `div` doesn’t generate any box, so its background, border and padding are not rendered. However the inherited properties like `color` and `font` have effect on the child (`span` element) as expected.

Also good reading on `display: contents`:

- [Get Ready for `display: contents;`](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/)
- [Vanishing boxes with display contents](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/01/29/vanishing-boxes-with-display-contents/)

---

The `display` property doesn't change how the DOM is rendered just style it, so a `last-child` it always be a `last-child` no matter the `display` you use (even using `display: none`)

As you can see in the snippet below the properties belonging to box-model don't get inherit by children when parent is `display: contents`

```css
.section {
  margin: 10px
}

form {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 10px solid red;
  padding: 10px
}

.section:first-child {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px green;
}

.section:last-child {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<Accordion>
  <form style="display: contents">
    <div class="section">first child of form</div>
    <div class="section">last child of form</div>
  </form>
  <div class="section">first and last child of Accordion</div>
</Accordion>

<hr />

<Accordion>
  <form style="display: flex">
    <div class="section">first child of form</div>
    <div class="section">last child of form</div>
  </form>
  <div class="section">first and last child of Accordion</div>
</Accordion>

<hr />

<Accordion>
  <form>
    <div class="section">first child of form</div>
    <div class="section">nth child 2 of form - even if last child is display:none</div>
    <div class="section" style="display: none">last child of form</div>
  </form>
  <div class="section">first and last child of Accordion</div>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: "The display property doesn't change how the DOM is rendered just style it, so a last-child it always be a last-child no matter the display you use (even using display: none)" That sentence really put everything into perspective.